# Showing [Installed Version] when upgrading with dnf in CentOS/Redhat/Fedora/Rocky Linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fedora, dnf

When running `dnf upgrade` it only shows the new version of a package about to be upgraded. But I would like to see what the currently installed version of the package is too. Without having to go look up the installed packages etc. Basically I would like to add a column to the upgrade/update list that gets shown when I get asked if it should continue or not.

Currently it looks like

```
Package         Arch        Version         Repository      Size
```

But I would like to add a column of `Installed Version` like this

```
Package         Arch        Installed Version       Version         Repository      Size
```

Is this possible to do in `dnf` at the moment or is it something that would have to be added to the code? Tried to google it but couldn't find anything about this.

Edit:
Thought that I could give you a few reasons why this would be helpful, and I came up with this right of off my head. If you know more reasons please enlighten me!

- That you can see what typ of upgrade your getting. Like if it is a Major/Minor/Patch. So you can be al little more prepared on what your getting yourself into when saying yes on the continuation question.
- If you are managing multiple servers/computers and upgrade them, you can more easily see if they are on different versions to begin with. Which could mean that the update could impact differently.

Comment: I don't see anything either. The old version is logged in the history after the package is updated, but that might not help you very much.

Comment: Not what you asked for, but with a little script/pipe you could `dnf check-upgrade -q`, then `cut` the package names out and `rpm -q <packagename>` ... and format the output columns however you like.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Well I guess I could do that. but it feels like one of those times where you'd end up spending way more time on automating a task than it takes to just check it manually. Fitting [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1319/). ;)

Comment: Y M M V  :-) ;-)